# How to get last updated date for k8s hpa?

Tags: kubernetes, horizontalpodautoscaler

I tried with the below command but it provides only the created date. How do I get when was it last updated?

```
kubectl describe hpa -n xyz hpa-hello
```

Example: Today I create a hpa with max replica 3 and tomorrow I apply the same yaml but with max replica 6. If I do that, I can see only the created date and not the updated date. The description correctly shows the updated max replicas as 6

Update: There is no direct way to obtain this information !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Assume here that the last updated date or time nothing but when was last auto scaled?
To get details about the Horizontal Pod Autoscaler, you can use kubectl get hpa with the -o yaml flag. The status field contains information about the current number of replicas and any recent autoscaling events.

```
kubectl get hpa <hpa name> -o yaml
```

In this output we can see the last transition times along with messages.
Refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/horizontal-pod-autoscaling#kubectl-get) which might help you and also to [view](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/horizontal-pod-autoscaling#viewing) the details about the HPA.

Edit 1:
Moreover, I have gone through many docs and I don't think we can get the info about it from a get command. For this, an [auditing resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-cluster/audit/) in k8's can be created to log all activities generated by users for a specific type of resource . This might help you to find the logs.

Comment: No. I want to know when the auto scaler got updated. Example: Today I create a hpa with max replica 3 and tomorrow i apply the same yaml but with max replica 6. If I do that, i can see only the created date and not the updated date.  The description correctly shows the updated max replicas as 6

Comment: @ArunPrakashNagendran : I have gone through many docs i dont think we cannot get the info about it from a get command. For this, an [auditing resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-cluster/audit/) in k8's can be created  to log all activities generated by users for a specific type of resource . This might help you to find the logs.

Comment: Thanks for checking this. Even I think there is no straightforward way to get this information.